# Using subquery in SQL that is returning Every derived table must have its own alias error?

Tags: sql

I'm finding it difficult to grasp why this following query wouldn't work:

```
SELECT rating_count 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         title, 
         COUNT(rating) AS rating_count
     FROM series
     LEFT JOIN reviews ON series.id = reviews.series_id
     GROUP BY series.id);
```

The result of the subquery is the following:

[image]

Why is it that when I try to query for the `rating_count`, it wouldn't work? I thought I could request this. My intention is filter those rows that have `rating_count = 0`.

I wanted to try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         title, COUNT(rating) AS rating_count
     FROM series
     LEFT JOIN reviews ON series.id = reviews.series_id
     GROUP BY series.id) 
WHERE rating_count = 0;
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags. [Edit] your question to tag correctly. Though I *suspect* this is MySQL, as SQL Server would give the errors *"Incorrect syntax near ';'."* and *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."* respectively, *not* alert you that you are missing an alias.

Comment: @Larnu, and with no dbms tag, ISO SQL is expected - which doesn't require the alias.

Comment: That doesn't really change the point though, @jarlh . Flagging conflicting RDBMS is also not helpful. Though, in truth the error the OP was getting was telling them the problem... Reading is hard, I suppose?

Comment: @Larnu reading isn't hard, just not familiar with the error messages in SQL... Just learning, but promise won't happen again. Very constructive comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly as the error says, you need to alias your derived table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    title, 
    count(rating) as rating_count
    FROM series
    LEFT JOIN reviews
        ON series.id = reviews.series_id
    GROUP BY series.id
    ) AS t
WHERE rating_count=0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going nuts, so you should always provide an alias to a derived table ! thanks

Comment: This is so annoying, ANSI/ISO SQL and most dbms's don't care, but some others require the alias.